Serving JavaScript with Xampp on Windows
I am using Xampp (PHP 8.1.6, Apache 2.4.53) on Windows 11 for development work. I have a JavaScript file (stock standard minified JQuery) which is not running on my page when it is served from the development environment but it runs correctly when served from the production server, which is typical Linux shared hosting.
The browser console shows that the file is being served with response code 200, correct content type, and correct file size. The only difference is that the production server is running it through compression and serving it gzipped, although the actual file on disk is not compressed.
But if I load the script alone in my browser, the content for the script served by the development environment shows unprintable characters whereas the script served by the live environment is fully legible.
I would appreciate any pointers to get JavaScript serving correctly in the development environment. My guess is a Windows/Linux code page issue perhaps?
Thanks all
